# CLion error list window

Tags: clion

Is there anyway to display error list in Clion, something like the one in Visual Studio?

[image: VS Error list]

Comment: You have the message window and that's it.

Comment: Awesome, I didn't have enabled this by default and was looking for something like "error list" as it is in Visual. Thank you!

Comment: It should show up automatically when you build.